# call an Asp Action from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a table that will use is populated by `javascript` when another table option is clicked. All of this works no problem, when I add the delete button to the table the `onClick` event fires but this isn't ever called in asp.net.

```
function DeleteLink(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PublicPages/LinkDelete/',
        data:{ id:id }
    });
}
```

please tell me where I've gone wrong.

I have tried

```
function DeleteLink(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PublicPages/LinkDelete/' + id
}
```

as well

UPDATE:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LinkDelete(Guid id)
    {
        var pageId = _linkDataProvider.FindById(id).PublicPage.Id;
        _linkDataProvider.Delete(id);
        var page = await _pageDataProvider.FindById(pageId);
        var viewModel = _pageDataProvider.ConvertToViewModel(page);
        return View("Details", viewModel);
    }
```

UPDATE2

`app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Flooring}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });`

Comment: If your `DeleteLink` action has `HttpPost` attribute you need to specify http method. Try to add `type: "POST"` in ajax setting.

Comment: please share the `Action` method also.

Comment: ` $.post({  url: '/PublicPages/LinkDelete/', data:{ id:id } });` this should work.

Comment: Please also share your routing setup.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify http method in ajax settings. Try to change your javascript like below:

```
function DeleteLink(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type = 'POST',
        url: '/PublicPages/LinkDelete/' + id
    });
}
```

**Update**

If you prefer to use `data:{ id:id }` then you would need to create a model class:

```
public class DeleteModel
{
    public Guid Id{get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LinkDelete([FromBody]DeleteModel model)
....
```

Comment: this still is not firing LinkDelete